# Windows Store App Development

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am new to Windows Store App Development. I have installed Windows Phone 8 sdk, but when I am creating an app I am getting an error

```
unable to copy the file"FlipCycleTileLarge.png" from the project template to the project. Access is Denied.
```

I also tried running VS as Adminstrator but it doesnt work.

Comment: Which SDK did you install, Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Windows Phone 8 sdk....

Comment: Where is your project saved?  There can sometimes be permissions issue, for example if files are saved to SkyDrive.

Comment: Also, you are creating a phone app, correct?

Comment: @WaltRitscher: Yes,iam creating a phone app.I tried saving into some other drive and it works ! thanks .But now iam getting System.NullReferenceException at the MainPage.xaml .What is that ???

Comment: You need to provide code if you want help with null reference exception.  Did you write any code or add any XAML to MainPage.xaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Updating your sdk to win8.1 or the image logo is giving error's because you're targeting right protected areas. 
Try todo in other drives. and create a project from scratch and run. do tellme if you have any errors.